# Where can I find the names of default relationships in SugarCRM?

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I've been stuck a while because in a Cases logic hook I couldn't load contacts_cases relationship as I did with another custom relationship, like this:

```
$bean->load_relationship('cases_lines');
$lines = $bean->cases_lines->getBeans();

$bean->load_relationship('contacts_cases');
$contacts->$bean->contacts_cases->getBeans();
```

The first was working, the latter wasn't.
I found out that I was using the wrong name because it's a default relationship and its name is 'contacts' and not 'contacts_cases' as I supposed, so I change my code like this:

```
$bean->load_relationship('contacts');
$contacts->$bean->contacts->getBeans();
```

and now it's working perfectly.
I didn't found in documentation the naming difference between default and custom relationship, I found the solution above only debugging SugarBean method 'load_relationship' and printing out the loaded relationships.

This line of code

```
error_log('LOADED RELATIONSHIPS '.print_r($this->loaded_relationships, true));
```

printed out

```
Array\n(\n    [0] => cases_lines\n    [1] => contacts\n)\n
```

In Studio the relationship appears as 'contacts_cases', the only place where I found the name 'contacts' is in file modules/Cases/vardefs.php

```
'contacts' =>
array (
  'name' => 'contacts',
  'type' => 'link',
  'relationship' => 'contacts_cases',
  'source'=>'non-db',
      'vname'=>'LBL_CONTACTS',
),
```

Also in relationships table the relationship_name is 'contacts_cases'.

Is there any place where I can see the real names that I must use when calling load_relationship or the only solution is looking in vardefs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest single source is to look into the cache directory because this merges all custom and out-of-the-box fields and relationships into one big array. To see all relationships from an Account perspective, check `cache/modules/Accounts/Accountsvardefs.php` and look for the `relationships` key and any `fields` where the `type` parameter is `link`. You'll find "stock" relationships like `contacts` and `opportunities` as well any and all custom relationships are built into that array.

Note that custom relationships will be called different things depending on the object you're working with. For example, a custom one-to-many relationships between custom modules *Meals* and *Ingredients* might be named `key_meals_ingredients_meals` on the Meals side and `key_meals_ingredients_ingredients` on the Ingredients side.

You can also find these in the user interface using Studio. Navigate into Studio, then your module, then into the Relationships table. The Name column on the left of the Relationships table is the value you're after.

Comment: Thanks, surely having a single file to look is helpful, it's only strange that I have to call differently default and custom relationships (default with the field name, custom with relationship name).  
I always used the name appearing in Studio, it's the first time I noticed this difference.  

I checked your other hint, and I noticed that all my custom relationships are called the same in both sides, could this thing depend on sugarcrm version?

Comment: A relationship is a `vardef` or a `relationship` not based on whether it is stock or custom, but based on what the convention was when it was created. As confusing as it is, you'll find stock relationships both ways. Part of it is whether it's a one/many or many/many relationship. Either way, that's why it's always helpful to check the cache files :)

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all possible values for `load_relationship`, use this code snippet:

```php
$rels = [];
foreach ($bean->getFieldDefinitions() as $key=>$val) {
    if (isset($val['type']) && $val['type'] === 'link') {
        $rels[] = $key;
    }
}
```

This starts with a `$bean` (for example, inside a logic hook) and produces a `rels[]` array with all valid relationship names.

This bit of code is meant as temporary help, use it to get the list and pick your correct value, then remove this code.

This uses the same set of definitions that the `load_relationship` function uses, so it should be accurate.

Comment: This is for SuiteCRM, I guess it's the same in Sugar, but I didn't try it there.